# another doxygen generating nothing

Tags: doxygen

i use doxygen 1.8.15 for the first time. 
I generate `Doxyfile` by `doxygen -g` and try to create documentation just by `doxygen`.

Among other i have in the base directory `test.cpp` looking like this:

```
/**
 * This is a test. doc for an enum
 */
enum Test {
        /**
         * doc for an item
         */
        SomeItem
};
```

I expect the html output in `html/index.html` but this is essentially an empty site. 
The following is an extract of the output:

```
Parsing files
Preprocessing /home/ernst/Ankrit/Software/Products/Recon/recon/Mbed/main.cpp...
Parsing file /home/ernst/Ankrit/Software/Products/Recon/recon/Mbed/main.cpp...
Reading /home/ernst/Ankrit/Software/Products/Recon/recon/Mbed/mbed_settings.py...
Parsing file /home/ernst/Ankrit/Software/Products/Recon/recon/Mbed/mbed_settings.py...
Preprocessing /home/ernst/Ankrit/Software/Products/Recon/recon/Mbed/test.cpp...
Parsing file /home/ernst/Ankrit/Software/Products/Recon/recon/Mbed/test.cpp...
Building group list...
```

As you can see `test.cpp` is inside. But in the results nothing on cpp shows up, only `mbed_settings`. 
What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When e.g. cpp code doxygen has the "habit" of not finding some information when no corresponding `.h` file is present.

With the aid of the `\file` command this problem can be overcome, so the code:

```
/// \file

/**
 * This is a test. doc for an enum
 */
enum Test {
        /**
         * doc for an item
         */
        SomeItem
};
```

gives the requested result.

Comment: wow great.... but there seems no hint in the docs `http://www.doxygen.nl/`, or did i oversee??

Comment: No probably you didn't oversee it, unfortunately one of the hidden gems.

Comment: Not so hidden. It is mentioned here http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#structuralcommands (check the "attention" section) and in the FAQ (http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html, second and third questions)

Comment: Apparently I don't know all the gems of doxygen either.